# JPA auto-generated key not reflected in foreign key of child table

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, hsqldb

Parent Table:

```
@Table(name="parent_table_t")
public class ParentTable implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name="contact_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer contactId;
---------
---------
@OneToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parentTable")
private ChildTable childTable;
}
```

Child Table:

```
@Table(name="child_table_t")
public class ChildTable implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name="child_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer childId;

@Column(name="contact_id")
private Integer contactId;

@JoinColumn(name="contact_id", referencedColumnName = "contact_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private ParentTable parentTable;
}
```

My requirement is when contact_id is generated in Parent_table_t, it should be copied into contact_id of child_table_t when saved.

When I am calling saveAndFlush / save on Parent Table Entity, it is:
Generating the auto-increment for Parent->contact_id.
But Child_table_t -> contact_id is always null.
Can someone please help in this.
I am using in-memorty hsqldb with spring-boot and JPA.

Comment: You need to remove insertable=false, updatable=false **and** ensure both sides of the relationship are set i.e. parentTable in child = the parent being persisted.

Answer (score 0):

You marked the relationship @JoinColumn with insertable=false, updatable=false, likely because you have an integer mapping for the column as well.  Unfortunately, these settings prevent JPA from setting it with values from the relationship, which instead is forced to set the column with the value in the contactId attribute.

Put the insertable=false, updatable=false on the @Column instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but still Child_table_t -> contactId is null.

Comment: do I need to initialize parentTable / childTable variables?